# Representation of group

Tags: representation-theory

The definition of representation in Knapp Is: a continuous homomorphism f:G in GL(V) such that f(g)v Is continuous. What represent f(g)v? Is f(g) and then it Is applicate to v?

Comment: I think you mean f:G -> GL(V) then for g in G, f(g) is an element of GL(V), i.e. an invertible linear map from V to V. So f(g)v would be the result of applying linear map f(g) to vector v in V.

Comment: yes, and in L^2(G) for example, v  will be a function? because i'm reading the left regular representazion on L^2(G) and i have g \to f(g^-1v) so what it means?

Comment: Well if V is a vector space whose elements are functions, then yes, v will be a function.